# "Carroty head", what could it possibly mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrase-usage

What do you think "carroty head" means in this sentence? Is this supposed to refer to hair color, head shape, maybe? It's from the opening page of Remarque's All Quiet On The Western Front:

> The cook with his **carroty** head is begging us to eat; he beckons with his ladle to every one that passes, and spoons him out a great dollop.

Comment: "Carroty head" isn't idiomatic English, so we'll never know for sure what is meant in that book, but "carrot top" always means red hair colour, so that's a good guess

Comment: Also that's an english translation of a german book, so it might be a translation of a more common expression. I agree with the above comment it could mean red hair, or it might just mean that his head looks like a carrot in some way (wide at the top?)

Comment: Is it possible the cook had carrot fragments in his hair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Carrot head" or "Carrot top" is a somewhat childish and mildly rude way to refer to a person with red hair.  That seems to be the sense here:  The cook had reddish hair.

The other alternatives "shaped like a carrot" or "with carrots in his hair" can't be completely dismissed, but seem much less likely to me.

This is confirmed by comparing with the German:

> *So ein Fall ist schon lange nicht mehr dagewesen: der Küchenbulle mit seinem roten Tomatenkopf bietet das Essen direkt an;
> jedem, der vorbeikommt, winkt er mit seinem Löffel zu und
> füllt ihm einen kräftigen Schlag ein."*

The cook is described as having "*roten Tomatenkopf*" literally "red tomato-head"

Comment: "Küchenbulle" is also a more expressive word than "cook"

Comment: As a life-long carrot head, aka "ginger" or "that red-head", or "rooikop" and a few others, I can confirm the diagnosis.

Comment: @RonaldSole - when I was 14, my father said it was time for him to give me some advice about "women". I waited agog. The total of his advice was: 1. Never put anything in writing. 2. Do not have anything to do with redheads, as they tend to have bad tempers. 3. Don't go out with Welsh women, for the same reason. In the event, my first big affair was with a beautiful girl from Cardiff with pre-Raphaelite red hair.